# Get all tags for resources retrieved with AWS Config

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-config

I'm using an AWS Custom Config Rule created with Lambda. I'm using an example from [the official AWS docs (Example Function for Periodic Evaluations
)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/evaluate-config_develop-rules_python-sample.html)

```
resource_identifiers = []
for resource_type in resource_types:
     resource_identifiers.append(AWS_CONFIG_CLIENT.list_discovered_resources(resourceType=resource_type))
```

The above works fine. I end up with a list of dicts (all resources with different resource types). A dict looks like this. ([source](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/config.html#ConfigService.Client.list_discovered_resources))

```
{
    'resourceIdentifiers': [
        {
            'resourceType': 'AWS::EC2::CustomerGateway'|'AWS::EC2::EIP'|'AWS::EC2::Host'|'AWS::EC2::Instance'|'AWS::EC2::InternetGateway'|'AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl'|'AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface'|'AWS::EC2::RouteTable'|'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'|'AWS::EC2::Subnet'|'AWS::CloudTrail::Trail'|'AWS::EC2::Volume'|'AWS::EC2::VPC'|'AWS::EC2::VPNConnection'|'AWS::EC2::VPNGateway'|'AWS::EC2::RegisteredHAInstance'|'AWS::EC2::NatGateway'|'AWS::EC2::EgressOnlyInternetGateway'|'AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint'|'AWS::EC2::VPCEndpointService'|'AWS::EC2::FlowLog'|'AWS::EC2::VPCPeeringConnection'|'AWS::Elasticsearch::Domain'|'AWS::IAM::Group'|'AWS::IAM::Policy'|'AWS::IAM::Role'|'AWS::IAM::User'|'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer'|'AWS::ACM::Certificate'|'AWS::RDS::DBInstance'|'AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup'|'AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup'|'AWS::RDS::DBSnapshot'|'AWS::RDS::DBCluster'|'AWS::RDS::DBClusterSnapshot'|'AWS::RDS::EventSubscription'|'AWS::S3::Bucket'|'AWS::S3::AccountPublicAccessBlock'|'AWS::Redshift::Cluster'|'AWS::Redshift::ClusterSnapshot'|'AWS::Redshift::ClusterParameterGroup'|'AWS::Redshift::ClusterSecurityGroup'|'AWS::Redshift::ClusterSubnetGroup'|'AWS::Redshift::EventSubscription'|'AWS::SSM::ManagedInstanceInventory'|'AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm'|'AWS::CloudFormation::Stack'|'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer'|'AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup'|'AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration'|'AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy'|'AWS::AutoScaling::ScheduledAction'|'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'|'AWS::CodeBuild::Project'|'AWS::WAF::RateBasedRule'|'AWS::WAF::Rule'|'AWS::WAF::RuleGroup'|'AWS::WAF::WebACL'|'AWS::WAFRegional::RateBasedRule'|'AWS::WAFRegional::Rule'|'AWS::WAFRegional::RuleGroup'|'AWS::WAFRegional::WebACL'|'AWS::CloudFront::Distribution'|'AWS::CloudFront::StreamingDistribution'|'AWS::Lambda::Function'|'AWS::NetworkFirewall::Firewall'|'AWS::NetworkFirewall::FirewallPolicy'|'AWS::NetworkFirewall::RuleGroup'|'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application'|'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion'|'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment'|'AWS::WAFv2::WebACL'|'AWS::WAFv2::RuleGroup'|'AWS::WAFv2::IPSet'|'AWS::WAFv2::RegexPatternSet'|'AWS::WAFv2::ManagedRuleSet'|'AWS::XRay::EncryptionConfig'|'AWS::SSM::AssociationCompliance'|'AWS::SSM::PatchCompliance'|'AWS::Shield::Protection'|'AWS::ShieldRegional::Protection'|'AWS::Config::ConformancePackCompliance'|'AWS::Config::ResourceCompliance'|'AWS::ApiGateway::Stage'|'AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi'|'AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Stage'|'AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api'|'AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline'|'AWS::ServiceCatalog::CloudFormationProvisionedProduct'|'AWS::ServiceCatalog::CloudFormationProduct'|'AWS::ServiceCatalog::Portfolio'|'AWS::SQS::Queue'|'AWS::KMS::Key'|'AWS::QLDB::Ledger'|'AWS::SecretsManager::Secret'|'AWS::SNS::Topic'|'AWS::SSM::FileData'|'AWS::Backup::BackupPlan'|'AWS::Backup::BackupSelection'|'AWS::Backup::BackupVault'|'AWS::Backup::RecoveryPoint'|'AWS::ECR::Repository'|'AWS::ECS::Cluster'|'AWS::ECS::Service'|'AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition'|'AWS::EFS::AccessPoint'|'AWS::EFS::FileSystem'|'AWS::EKS::Cluster'|'AWS::OpenSearch::Domain'|'AWS::EC2::TransitGateway'|'AWS::Kinesis::Stream'|'AWS::Kinesis::StreamConsumer'|'AWS::CodeDeploy::Application'|'AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentConfig'|'AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup'|'AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate'|'AWS::ECR::PublicRepository'|'AWS::GuardDuty::Detector'|'AWS::EMR::SecurityConfiguration'|'AWS::SageMaker::CodeRepository'|'AWS::Route53Resolver::ResolverEndpoint'|'AWS::Route53Resolver::ResolverRule'|'AWS::Route53Resolver::ResolverRuleAssociation'|'AWS::DMS::ReplicationSubnetGroup'|'AWS::DMS::EventSubscription'|'AWS::MSK::Cluster'|'AWS::StepFunctions::Activity'|'AWS::WorkSpaces::Workspace'|'AWS::WorkSpaces::ConnectionAlias'|'AWS::SageMaker::Model'|'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener'|'AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine'|'AWS::Batch::JobQueue'|'AWS::Batch::ComputeEnvironment'|'AWS::AccessAnalyzer::Analyzer'|'AWS::Athena::WorkGroup'|'AWS::Athena::DataCatalog'|'AWS::Detective::Graph'|'AWS::GlobalAccelerator::Accelerator'|'AWS::GlobalAccelerator::EndpointGroup'|'AWS::GlobalAccelerator::Listener'|'AWS::EC2::TransitGatewayAttachment'|'AWS::EC2::TransitGatewayRouteTable'|'AWS::DMS::Certificate',
            'resourceId': 'string',
            'resourceName': 'string',
            'resourceDeletionTime': datetime(2015, 1, 1)
        },
    ],
    'nextToken': 'string'
}
```

Now how I can I retrieve the tags for each resource? The resource type can be different. There is a method [`list_tags_for_resource`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/config.html#ConfigService.Client.list_tags_for_resource) but it requires the `resource_arn` which I don't know. I only know id, type and name. I can try to substitute an arn for each type but this will take too long and will be too complex. Then I have to initiate a client for each resource_type and request the tags.

Is there a clear way on how to retrieve the tags for a resource?

Comment: Shouldn't the resouceId actually be the ARN of the resource?

Comment: unfortunately not (always), for EC2 it were instance Ids instead of the arn

Answer (score 0):

you will just need to find the ARN of each resource, at time they will not show in AWS console. Here are examples of 3 types of resources & their ARN

```
arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:xxx:ec2/vol-xxx
arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:xxx:snapshot/snap-xxx
arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:xxx:instance/i-xxx
```

Then get tags like below

aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --profile xxx--region us-east-1

```
import boto3
AWS_REGION = "us-east-1"
AWS_PROFILE = "xxx"
session=boto3.session.Session(profile_name=AWS_PROFILE)
#
client = session.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi',region_name=AWS_REGION)
client.get_resources(
    TagFilters=[
        {
            'Key': 'Owner',
            'Values': [
                'xxxx'
            ]
        },
    ],
    ResourceTypeFilters=[
        's3'
]
    )
```

```
To get a list of all tag values

The following get-tag-values example displays all of the values used for the specified key for all resources in the

aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-tag-values \
    --key=Environment
```